# find command not working in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

When I run any type of `find` command it displays the following error:

```
phoenix@phoenix-Satellite-C640:~$ find ~ -name file1
pgrep: invalid option -- 'm'

Usage:
 pgrep [options] <pattern>

Options:
 -d, --delimiter <string>  specify output delimiter
 -l, --list-name           list PID and process name
 -v, --inverse             negates the matching
 -w, --lightweight         list all TID
 -c, --count               count of matching processes
 -f, --full                use full process name to match
 -g, --pgroup <id,...>     match listed process group IDs
 -G, --group <gid,...>     match real group IDs
 -n, --newest              select most recently started
 -o, --oldest              select least recently started
 -P, --parent <ppid,...>   match only child processes of the given parent
 -s, --session <sid,...>   match session IDs
 -t, --terminal <tty,...>  match by controlling terminal
 -u, --euid <id,...>       match by effective IDs
 -U, --uid <id,...>        match by real IDs
 -x, --exact               match exactly with the command name
 -F, --pidfile <file>      read PIDs from file
 -L, --logpidfile          fail if PID file is not locked
 --ns <pid>                match the processes that belong to the same
                           namespace as <pid>
 --nslist <ns,...>         list which namespaces will be considered for
                           the --ns option.
                           Available namespaces: ipc, mnt, net, pid, user, uts

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see pgrep(1).
```

Comment: What is the output of `type -a find`?

Comment: By default, if you use form find, give you permission error, then use sudo find. You can also use find . | grep or find . | ack

Comment: Seems like somebody has either made an alias or function named `find` that is actually calls `pgrep`  instead of `find`. `pgep` doesn't have ` -m` option , so it fails while reading `-name`.  Hence the error.  ByteCommander got the right idea. Find out what `find` is , and you will find your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Serg answered the question in the comments - someone aliased find to pgrep. Type 'alias' without any arguments and it will show you all the aliases.

Somewhere along the line you executed a shell script that set that alias. If it wasn't one of the standard ones like .profile, .bash_profile or .bashrc, it was something that was perhaps specific to your project or local environment.